# Проблемы с  $_GET[id]; запросом

Tags: .htaccess, php, запрос

Вот сам код запроса все работает нормально когда доступ к странице идет вида [site.com/profile?id=123](http://site.com/profile?id=123) или [site.com/123](http://site.com/123) но выдает ошибку когда доступ идет вида [site.com/idn123](http://site.com/idn123)

Вот код который выдергивает id пользователя

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; } 
else
{ exit("Error 1 !");} 
if($id == 0) {
exit("<p>Bad URL</p>");
}
```

При запросе вида [site.com/idn123](http://site.com/idn123) выдает ошибку bad url,
в .htaccess вот что вписано для изменения на idn

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ idn?id=$1
RewriteRule ^idn([0-9]+)$ profile?id=$1
```

Подскажите, что не так и почему он выдает ошибку? Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Выполняется первое условие в .htaccess

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile?id=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  RewriteRule ^idn([a-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Вот попробуй так, если я правильно понял!

Comment: не помогает( Надо что бы код php мог определять Ид запроса idn так же как и у запроса profile?id=